# How to access instance model inside a static method in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mongoose

I am trying to create a findOrCreate method in a mongoose model.

```
UserSchema.statics.findOrCreate = (newUserData, next) ->
  @findOne { id: newUserData.id }, (err, user) ->
    return next err  if err
    if not user
      self = mongoose.model 'user'
      user = new self newUserData
      user.save (err) ->
        return err if err
    next null, user
```

My main question is:
Am I instantiating an new instance of the user model inside a static method correctly?

```
self = mongoose.model 'user'
user = new self newUserData
```

I do not see any errors, it ran without any problems. But there is no new document inserted into the database.

Answer (score 0):

did you set the 'safe' option on your schema?

see here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#safe

Comment: This document stated that the default option is set to 'safe: true', so I suppose I do, since I did not specific it in my code.

Comment: ok. have you tried listening for errors on the connection (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save)? maybe something goes wrong in the middle.

Comment: No, it did not give me any errors. eventually i found this (https://github.com/drudge/mongoose-findorcreate) and it solved my problem.